# Изучение железа

Tags: железо, ос, cpu, информатика

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста-посоветуйте книги по железу ПК, сам я знаю максимум наличие CPU и Main memory у компьютера. То есть знания у меня вообще начальные и хотел спросить у вас, книги, которые обучат знать как работает и что внутри компьютера.
Вот две книги-"Код. Тайный язык информатики" и "архитектура" Таненбаум уже просмотрены:)

Comment: Если после "просмотра" Таненбаума вы знаете только процессор и память, то возможно стоит его все таки почитать, а не просто "посмотреть".

Comment: хотел посоветовать «энциклопедию профессора фортрана» по старой памяти, но тут глаз зацепился за другое... ты прочитал «архитектуру компьютера» и до сих пор знаешь только «наличие CPU и Main memory» o_O?

Comment: я неправильно выразился, то есть я их не осилил, вообще))

Comment: "Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера" Дэвид и Сарра Харрис

Answer (score 1):

Можно, конечно, попробовать дать ссылку во что-то относительно монументальное, например, в книги Таненбаума. У него есть все что нужно, чтобы превратиться из неуча в компьютерного гуру: архитектура компьютера, операционные системы, компьютерные сети, да еще и обновляются издания относительно оперативно. Но это будет очень долго и больно.

Но честно, не знаю ни одного человека, который бы начинал с книжек. Вы просто не будете понимать что в них происходит. Самый жизненый путь - проапгрейдить свой компьютер. Заменяя по одному компоненты хочешь-нехочешь, а почитаешь как что устроено, чтобы более-менее осознано сделать выбор. Имея такие базовые знания уже можно пытаться что-то читать, хотя все еще какие-то "техно"-блогеры будут предпочтительнее, т.к. жрут меньше времени и проще воспринимаются. Главное все на веру не воспринимать, даже адекватные ребята иногда такую чушь несут, волосы выдирать с темечка начинаешь. Слушаете разных, сравниваете показания, более-менее к истине придете.

Еще есть всевозможные концентрированные ресурсы по теме и онлайн-курсы. С ними сложно что-то советовать, т.к. когда не знаешь темы выбрать из многообразия что-то действительно хорошее можно только наугад, а когда знаешь слушать несколько разных курсов, чтобы понять какой лучше, никто не будет, потому и посоветовать мало кто что-то может. Можете попробовать посмотреть всякие курсеры, например [вот](https://www.coursera.org/learn/arkhitektura-evm) бесплатный. В теории это промежуточный вариант по скорости и эффективности между самобразом и книгошерстением.